# FactoryGirl: has_many :through, validates_presence_of: association error: can't be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm receiving the below test failure on my Article factory, which has a has_many through:, validates_presence_of relationship with my Categories model. The Categories need to exist before the Article is created, so I've set up a before(:create), create_list hook to create and associate some categories with the article being created, but I'm receiving the below failure. I've also tried using *association* (e.g. association :categories, factory: :category), but based on what I've read, the relationships that my models have (have_many :through), requires I use the before(:create) hooks. What am I missing?

```
Failures:

  1) Factory Girl article factory is valid
     **Failure/Error: expect(factory).to be_valid, lambda { factory.errors.full_messages.join("\n") }
       Categories can't be blank**
     # ./spec/support/factories_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :articles
   ...
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories

  validates_presence_of :categories
  ...
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :articles, through: :article_categories
  ...
end

class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :article_id, :category_id

  belongs_to :article 
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Factories**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password 'GoodP@ssw0rd'
    password_confirmation 'GoodP@ssw0rd'
    user_name { Faker.bothify('??????????###') }

    after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      create_list(:article, rand(1..3), user: user)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title { Faker::Lorem.paragraph[0..(rand(11..63))] }
    content { Faker::Lorem.paragraph[0..(rand(150..5000))] }

    before(:create) do |article, evaluator|
      create_list(:category, rand(1..3), article: article)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    name { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article_category do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title { Faker::Lorem.paragraph[0..(rand(11..63))] }
    content { Faker::Lorem.paragraph[0..(rand(150..5000))] }
    categories { create_list(:category, rand(1..3)) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Ahh, perhaps `before(:create)` is run *after* validation takes place. I revised the answer above. Any luck now?

Comment: That did it; no way to do that using before(:xxx)? What if I wanted to use transient properties? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Good question. Perhaps the `after(:build)` hook will run prior to validations?